# How to display and update multiple image in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview

I want to display image from list of task which I pass the object of documentsnapshot into the edit task.
Here is my code.

ListOfTaskNotAccepted

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fyp/screen/RecordOfficer/EditTaskNotApprove.dart';
import 'package:fyp/shared/Loading.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';


class ListOfTaskNotAccepted extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListOfTaskNotAcceptedState createState() => _ListOfTaskNotAcceptedState();
}
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUser(BuildContext context) async* {
  final FirebaseUser rd = await auth.currentUser();
  yield* Firestore.instance.collection("Task").where('uid',isEqualTo: rd.uid).where("verified", isEqualTo: 'TidakSah').snapshots();
}
class _ListOfTaskNotAcceptedState extends State<ListOfTaskNotAccepted> {
  List<NetworkImage> _listOfImages = <NetworkImage>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Aduan Tidak Diterima"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
      body: Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: getUser(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
              return Loading();
            } else{
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                   DocumentSnapshot da = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    _listOfImages =[];
                    for(int i =0; i <da['url'].length; i++){
                      _listOfImages.add(NetworkImage(da['url'][i]));
                    }
                     DateTime myDateTime = (da['date']).toDate();
                    return Card(
                        child:ListTile(
                          title: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Sumber Aduan: ", style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(da['sumberAduan'], style: GoogleFonts.asap(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Nombor Aduan: ", style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(da['noAduan'], style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Lokasi: ", style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                      Text(da['kawasan'] + " " + da['naJalan'], style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                                Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("Kategori: ", style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                      Text(da['kategori'], style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                      height: 200,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.white
                                      ),
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      child: Carousel(
                                        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        images: _listOfImages,
                                        autoplay: false,
                                        indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                                        dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                                        animationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                                        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text("Catatan: ", style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                    Text(da['comments'], style: GoogleFonts.arimo(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                          onTap: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditTask(da:da)));}
                        )
                    );
                  });
               }
          }),
       )
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, I pass the documentsnapshot da in navigator. here is my code EditTask

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class EditTask extends StatefulWidget {
 final DocumentSnapshot da;

  const EditTask({Key key, this.da}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditTaskState createState() => _EditTaskState(da);
}

class _EditTaskState extends State<EditTask> {
  DocumentSnapshot da;
  _EditTaskState(DocumentSnapshot da){
    this.da = da;
  }
 TextEditingController _noAduan;
 TextEditingController _sumberAduan;
 TextEditingController _kategori;
  String _listOfImages;
  DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.now();
 @override
 void initState(){
   super.initState();
   _noAduan = TextEditingController(text: widget.da.data['noAduan']);
   _sumberAduan =TextEditingController(text: widget.da.data['sumberAduan']);
   _kategori = TextEditingController(text: widget.da.data['kategori']);
   myDateTime = (da.data['date']).toDate();
  _listOfImages = da.data['url'];

 }

  List <String> sumber = <String> ['Sistem Aduan MBPJ', 'Sistem Aduan Waze', 'Sistem Aduan Utiliti'];
  List <String> kate = <String> ['Segera', 'Pembaikan Biasa'];
  String kategori;
  String sumberAduan;
  File image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Kemaskini Aduan"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
    body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration:InputDecoration(
                    hintText: myDateTime.toString(),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                onChanged: (value){
                  setState(() {
                    myDateTime = value as DateTime;
                    print(myDateTime);
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextFormField(
                decoration:InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                controller: _noAduan,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                hint:Text(widget.da.data['sumberAduan']),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.perm_contact_calendar),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: sumberAduan,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    sumberAduan = newValue;
                    _sumberAduan.text = sumberAduan;
                  });
                },
                items: sumber.map((sum){
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: sum,
                    child: new Text(sum),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField(
                hint:Text(widget.da.data['kategori']),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.perm_contact_calendar),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                isExpanded: true,
                value: kategori,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    kategori = newValue;
                    _kategori.text = kategori;
                  });
                },
                items: kate.map((ka){
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: ka,
                    child: new Text(ka),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white
                    ),
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Carousel(
                      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                      autoplay: false,
                      images:Image.network(da.data['url']),
                      indicatorBgPadding: 5.0,
                      dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
                      animationCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

The error show that

> Error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

I had problem to display the image when user to want to edit specific task. I had tried many method to display specific image that user selected for updating. Is there anything method to display it? someone can explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a Image List. Look at the following exemple:

```
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
  items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber
          ),
          child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
        );
      },
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

You should change the way you are querying the images in the widget tree to something like the example above.

Comment: alright, thank you. later i will try this method

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> GridView.builder()

```
 List imagesLinks = [
"first link",
"second link",
"third link",
"fourth link",
"fifth link",
"sixth link",
"seventh link",
```

];

```
 GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            ),
            itemCount: imageLinks.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30,
                    child:Image.network('${imageLinks[index]}'),
                  ),
                  
                ],
              );
            },
          )
```

Comment: how to use gridView.builder() ?

Comment: checkout my new answer

Comment: list of images? you mean List<NetworkImage> ?

Comment: Can you show example on how to using list of images in gridview.builder?